GPU separate processors for transfer and compute
When using an API such as Vulkan it's possibly you have multiple different queue families to use. Sometimes you have a transfer family without graphics or compute. This means it's a specialised transfer family that's most likely the one that does DMA from to RAM to the GPU through the PCI-E. In the case where there's a compute queue without graphics it's likely that the GPU can have compute shaders dispatched on it, which (as I understand it) can do this asynchronously. What I want to know is, these processors that process commands on these queues, they're separate from each other? So let's say you a graphics queue, a compute queue on a specialised compute queue family and a transfer queue on a specialised transfer queue family, is it the case that each queue family is using processors of the GPU that are solely used ONLY for processing commands on that queue family? So the GPU comes with a whole bunch of processors and if you only use the graphics queue family you're only using a portion of the processors available on the GPU and the other processors are going to waste?
Also, I'm not that knowledgable about GPUs at all, but reading the specs of cards I never remember reading anything like x processors dedicated to compute, x processors dedicated to graphics, etc.

Vulkan is an abstract representation of a GPU interface. There are many different ways it can be implemented based on the underlying hardware. Queues are one such example of that. They're an abstract representation of the GPUs scheduling engine.
A GPU could have a single scheduler, and present a single queue. It could also have a single scheduler, and present a thousand queues that get aggregated in the kernel driver. On the contra a GPU could have 16 scheduling engines and present a single queue, or it could have 16 scheduling engines and present 16 queues.
For NVIDIA, the primary graphics unit is the Graphics Processing Cluster. Each GPC has a raster unit, and a number of Texture Processing Clusters, each with some number of Streaming Multiprocessors (typically 2). The SMs contain the CUDA cores. CUDA cores are NVIDIA's generic processing core, they can do single floating point and integer operations, with vector operations being sent to multiple cores (this is what they call Single Instruction, Multiple Thread [SIMT]). They are used for any shader, be it vertex, fragment, compute, etc. Despite NVIDIA's marketing, the CUDA cores are actually closer to the execution engines in an x86 CPU core, with the SM being the closest to a full CPU core (in actuality, the SMs themselves are often split into several partitions, each with their own CUDA cores, register file, scheduler, instruction decoder, and dispatch engine; and these are really the closest analogue to an x86 CPU core).
If we look at the latest Vulkan drivers for the GTX 1060[1], RTX 3070 Ti[2], and RTX 4090[3], we can see that they have near identical queue families. All them have 16 graphics queues, 2 transfer queues, and 8 compute queues. But, despite that, they all have very different hardware specs.
The GTX 1060 has 10 SMs, with the Pascal architecture having 2 SMs per TPC, and 5 TPCs per GPC, that means it has a single GPC[4]. Which more or less means it can only render one triangle at once (we'll just ignore the complexities of pipelining).
The RTX 3070 Ti has 48 SMs, with the Ampere architecture having 2 SMs per TPC, and 6 TPCs per GPC, that means it has 4 GPCs[5].
The RTX 4090 has 128 SMs, with the Ada Lovelace architecture having 2 SMs per TPC, and 6 TPCs per GPC, that means it has 11 GPCs[6] (not sure how the math is supposed to work on that one, but that is what they claim in Appendix A).
So, despite having vastly different parallelism capabilities, all of these GPUs present the same number of queues to applications. How they will handle those queues is an implementation detail. It's possible that the scheduler can perform task switching when waiting on some dependency. It's possible that a graphics operation could consume time on the graphics specific entities within the GPC (such as the rasterizer, the ROP, the PolyMorph Engine [tessellation], the RT cores, etc), which could provide time for a compute operation to make its way onto the CUDA cores. But it's impossible to know for certain how the GPU will parallelize these operations.
The assumption you can make, is that if the driver presents multiple queues, and you have multiple command lists that can be executed in parallel, the driver wants you to submit them in parallel queues (keep in mind that there are sometimes good reasons to submit multiple lists at once to vkQueueSubmit). It's possible that they won't be parallelized, it's also possible that submitting everything to a single queue will still result in parallelism; that's the nature of Vulkan's opaque interface, you can't know what will truly happen, only what the observed result will be.
